# Why leaflet.js adds more than one layer on map.addlayer(layer)?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, layer

I'm having a problem with leaflet. I try to add just one layer but leaflet adds more than one.

Here is the code:

```
var region_layer = L.geoJSON(layer);

// Count layers
console.log("Before adding a layer")
let i = 0;
mymap.eachLayer(function(){ i += 1; });
console.log('Map has', i, 'layers.');

// Add one layer
mymap.addLayer(region_layer);

// Count layers again
console.log("After adding a layer")
let z = 0;
mymap.eachLayer(function(){ z += 1; });
console.log('Map has', z, 'layers.');
```

And here is the output in the console:

```
Before adding a layer
Map has 0 layers.
After adding a layer
Map has 3 layers.
```

and here is the aspect of the first variable `layer`:

[image]

Why is leaflet adding 3 layers instead of just one?

Comment: a MultiPolygon shape, which is your geojson, is represented by a multi-dimensional array Check [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polygon)

Comment: @kboul Yes, but ins this case, the multidimensional array has only 1 dimension, since I have only1 polygon. And, in any case, this does not explain why I have 3 layers insted of 1 containing all the polygons, as it should be

Comment: `map.eachLayer()` iterates the whole structure of layers under the map. Not just the bottom-level polygons you've added. At a minimum it will find the `MultiPolygon` (which is a `layerGroup`) and each individual polygon. Use `instanceOf` to determine what it's finding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three instances of `Layer` in such a case are:

- An instance of [`L.GeoJSON`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#geojson), which parses your geojson data and spawns the needed instances of vector layers, which in your specific case is just...
- An instance of [`L.Polygon`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polygon), which is in charge of interpreting the coordinates and style of a specific polygon, and send that information to...
- An instance of [`L.Renderer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#renderer), which will be either a [`L.SVG`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#svg) or a [`L.Canvas`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#canvas) depending on your browser and the [`prefercanvas` option of your map instance](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-prefercanvas). The renderer is in charge of actually drawing visible stuff when needed (by either spawning `<svg>` elements in the DOM, or pushing pixels to a `<canvas>`, respectively).